# (DEPRECATED) Policy on Writing Critiques

Tags: discussion, status-declined, critique

<strike>We had a long, long discussion about this internally, and **we've decided that writing critique questions are officially on-topic**.</strike>

Edit: This is an older page, and has been superseded. **The original text follows, but is no longer site policy.** For more information, [see this page](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878/does-writers-se-accept-critique-requests).

---

In retrospect, the idea that a site about writing *doesn't allow talking about writing* (except in the rather narrow context of objective question examples) was, uh, a bad one. Yes, all critiques are subjective, but [we now allow some subjective topics so long as they are constructive](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). We think writing critiques, if properly directed, fit firmly in the "constructive" category.

Bottom line, a writing site should be *about writing*.

Therefore, we now welcome writing critique questions, provided ...

1. It is *your* actual real world writing
2. <strike>It is tagged [critique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critique)</strike>  (this tag is deprecated)
3. You **provide context** for the writing critique.

That is, you must tell us:

- what you were shooting for when you wrote that piece
- specifically what kind of critique feedback you are looking for
- also, what kinds of critique feedback we should avoid, to set boundaries

In other words, give us some direction, *don't* just paste a bunch of writing into a question and click submit, expecting coherent feedback.

See also: [What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work)

Answer (score 2):

This is great, but the real-world clause could be troubling. How do we satisfy this? Do we need to indicate where the writing is published? Much writing is done for its own sake, I know that a much of mine certainly is.

I'm looking forward to seeing how people use this, it should invigorate the site significantly.

Comment: what I mean is to avoid "let's write something brand new right *now* and critique it right here!"

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it goes without saying, but I'm thinking that critique questions, being subjective, should always be marked as community wiki.

Comment: hmm, I'm not so sure -- I think a good, reasoned critique takes effort to do well, and probably deserves a bit of reputation in return.

Comment: That's a good point. I was thinking more along the lines of not having one objective best answer.